# RDP to amazon box is not working from specific public IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, rdp

I have a strange problem with one of my m4.xlarge Windows boxes. I am able to log in from multiple PCs and networks however my client reports that he cant access the instance from his network.

- The VM is up and running
- Security group allows all traffic to the box (inbound/outbound)
- I am able to RDP and login from multiple PCs and networks
- The client states that his network is not blocking amazon

The error message the client is getting is attached. (Connection reset by peer) Could you please advise what should I check, or what could be the issue here? Thank you!

> Security group (Inbound / Outbound):
>    All traffic 0.0.0.0/0
>    All traffic ::/0

Comment: Can he access it from a different network? It's possible that Amazon has blocked his IP range at their external gateway. Some providers block ip ranges that generate a lot of bad traffic.

Comment: Might also check the Windows Firewall rules configured on that machine to see if it is blocking the IP for some reason. Maybe lots of failed RDP login attempts from that IP caused it to be blocked?

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys. There are no firewall rules configured on the box, but the idea with the blocked IP at amazon is really good one. Do you know how I would be able to check with Amazon that this is the case?

Comment: It isn't Amazon that would be doing the blocking -- it would be _his_ network. If he's using a laptop, ask him to try going via his cell phone network (personal hotspot) to see if it works, or try it from home. It might also be a configuration on his corporate computer that blocks access. (Ask him to try from a different computer!) Since you can access, it certainly isn't anything on AWS that is causing the problem.